# pgrouting extension slow in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: pgrouting, performance, postgresql-10

I am trying to implement routing on my road dataset using pgrouting function p**gr_createTopology**. It works fine on postgresql 9.6  but gets extremely slow and get stuck as nodes increase in postgresql 10. Both postgresql 9.6 and postgresql 10 are on the same computer.

This issue occurs when the dataset is large. For small datasets this function works completely fine in both postgresql 9.6 and 10.

I can not understand the reason why pgr_createTopology functions works completely fine in postgresql 9.6 and gets stuck in postgresql 10.

Is there anyone who could guide me regarding this issue?

(postgis version is 2.4.4 and pg_routing version is 2.6.0)

Comment: could you add the PostGIS/pgRouting version for both setups to your question. are you operating on the same data in both setups?

Comment: postgis version is 2.4.4 and pg_routing version is 2.6.0

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.